# Grease pencil seems to not care about the material

Tags: grease-pencil

I have this "x" as a grease object. For some reason, it does not want to render with blue border, and red fill:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Render result:

[image]

Any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck `Holdout` in the Fill section. See [Blender docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/materials/properties.html): holdout is meant to create 'holes' in your shapes.

[image: layer panel with 'use lights' unchecked]

And in the layers panel, uncheck `Use Lights`. When this is checked and there are no lights in the scene, all strokes and fills will be rendered in black, since there is no light to illuminate the colors.

Or you could add lights to your scene, of course, that's the other way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work sadly. I still don't see the colors rendered. Src file: https://we.tl/t-quIbQBHm5D

Comment: I've updated my answer. When you uncheck `Use Lights` in the layers panel, the colors will render.